# How to invoke the post title in magento?

Tags: wordpress, magento

i have installed magento and wordpress. they are on the same host.now, i want to get 5 of the latest post title in magento product page. how do i do?

Comment: If you used Fishpig, check their documentation.

Comment: what't the url of Fishpig thank you